Selecting the lowest price values on a 24 hours cycle to charge a battery
I want to select the minimum values over a 24 hour cycle to select the cheapest price per day.
                    Price  Carbon
Date and Hour
2024-01-01 00:00:00     20      40
2024-01-01 01:00:00     10      20
2024-01-01 02:00:00     20      40
2024-01-01 03:00:00     30      60
2024-01-01 04:00:00      5      10
2024-01-01 05:00:00      5      10
2024-01-01 06:00:00      5      10
2024-01-01 07:00:00      5      10
2024-01-01 08:00:00      5      10
2024-01-01 09:00:00     30      60
2024-01-01 10:00:00     40      80
2024-01-01 11:00:00     50     100
2024-01-01 12:00:00    100     200
2024-01-01 13:00:00    100     200
2024-01-01 14:00:00    100     200
2024-01-01 15:00:00    100     200
2024-01-01 16:00:00    100     200
2024-01-01 17:00:00    100     200
2024-01-01 18:00:00    100     200
2024-01-01 19:00:00    100     200
2024-01-01 20:00:00    100     200
2024-01-01 21:00:00    100     200

I used the function but I want to select the minimum hours over a 24 hour period.
import pandas as pd
out=df.nsmallest(7, columns=['Price'])
out

       Date and Hour  Price  Carbon
4   01/01/2024 04:00      5      10
5   01/01/2024 05:00      5      10
6   01/01/2024 06:00      5      10
7   01/01/2024 07:00      5      10
8   01/01/2024 08:00      5      10
28  02/01/2024 04:00      5      10
29  02/01/2024 05:00      5      10

However, I want to have the code to select the lowest values every 24 hours, i.e. repeat the cycle every day.

Extract date to group by day without hour
df['Date and Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date and Hour'])
df['Date'] = df['Date and Hour'].dt.date

Then select 7 smallest prices for each day using nsmallest
result = df.groupby('Date').apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(7, 'Price')).reset_index(drop=True)
print(result)

